# Finding the value of an antiderivative at a point, yet indefinite integral cannot be found

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem reads:

> If f is the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$ such that $f(0)=2$, then $f(4)=$...

The obvious solution (for me at least) would be to take the indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$, but that seems to be impossible... I have tried every method, but to no avail. Wolfram Alpha gives a result with imaginary numbers. I am probably not noticing something, any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: One could do it to whatever the desired precision by numerical integration.

Comment: Are you sure you're asked for an exact number? Not the answer of form
$$
f(4) = 2 + \int_0^4 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}
$$

Comment: Is this multiple choice?

Comment: I agree: uranix's answer is probably what is desired.

Comment: Yes, it's an exact number. There are 5 options: 3.205, 3.355, 3.505, 3.655, 3.805.  These are obviously calculator/machine obtained, but I'd like to know how to solve this without using a calculator if it is at all possible. (This is from my BC calc review packet, it's a "calculator" problem)

Comment: So what's wanted is **not** an exact number, but rather a numerical approximation accurate enough to distinguish between those 5 options.  Use whatever numerical integration methods you have available.  Simpson's rule, for example, should do reasonably well.

Comment: Rough estimate using Simpson's rule $$\int_0^4 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}} \approx \frac{2}{6}\left(1 + \frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}+ \frac{2}{\sqrt{9}} + \frac{4}{\sqrt{28}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{65}}\right) \approx 1.79$$ with error about $\epsilon \sim \frac{4}{90} \approx 0.044$. So the right is $3.805$

Comment: Thanks uranix! Got that from my calc too, I guess there really is no other way to solve this :(. Thanks Robert Israel for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  answer, according to Maple, is
$$ 2+{3}^{-1/4} \left( 2\,{\it EllipticK} \left( 1/4\,\sqrt {2}
 \left( 1+\sqrt {3} \right)  \right) -{\it EllipticF} \left( 2\,{
\frac {\sqrt [4]{3}}{1+\sqrt {3}}},1/4\,\sqrt {2} \left( 1+\sqrt {3}
 \right)  \right) -{\it EllipticF} \left( 2\,{\frac {\sqrt {5}\sqrt [4
]{3}}{5+\sqrt {3}}},1/4\,\sqrt {2} \left( 1+\sqrt {3} \right) 
 \right)  \right) 
$$
where EllipticK and EllipticF are complete and incomplete elliptic integrals of the first kind.

This tends to confirm that there is no elementary solution to the question.

Comment: Ok, guess I'll just write the definite integral solution proposed by uranix as my work for the problem. Thanks!